AWS SSL Certificate for Laravel on EC2 instance
I have Laravel application on EC2 instance on Ubuntu, also I have Application Load Balancer and verified AWS SSL certificate. But logically I can’t run Laravel without, NGINX or Apache.

I can adjust SSL with let’sencrypt using cerbot, but is it ok to use SSL inside EC2 instance instead of AWS SSL certificate?

Main Question: How to use AWS SSL certificate and why this certificate exists if everything needs Apache or NGINX, so AWS SSL certificate is useless.



Everything works well. Load Balancer adjusted through SSL certificate, In GoDaddy I added two CNAMEs:

The first one refers to the Load Balancer URL.
The second one is data (key, value) from ACM CNAME

NGINX server should be adjusted as the default server, without SSL keys.
The connection will look like this (In my head it looks like this):
Website -> HTTPS -> Load Balancer -> HTTP -> EC2

ACM certificates aren't useless.

It is designed to be used within AWS’s managed services.
Not everything needs Apache or NGINX so ACM can eliminate the need for manual server configuration for services.
It's has much longer validity period of up to 13 months compare to 3 months of Let's encrypt and have built-in renewal process.
And public ACM certificate is free so just use it.

